# How to get back if rooting or loading Cyanogenmod fails?

Tags: cyanogenmod, backup, restore, miui

I have an Mi Pad. I hate the UI & also hate the amount of memory it uses. 
I am planning to root it & load CM on to it. However, it's a fairly new tablet & still under warranty. Also I have never used CM before. So I want to be able to easily get back to the original OS without having to download stuff & try to install it again. This is my first time ever trying to root or try custom ROMs ever.

So what do I need to do to get back to my original OS/ROM easily?

Comment: You should be aware that the first step involves unlocking the bootloader will likely void the warranty and will automatically run a factory reset on the device, so you can't get it back to the original state, per say, but you can recover the original OS.

Comment: @EthanZ - ok - then I should probably wait till the warranty period is done. But even then, is there an easy way to get back the original OS?

Comment: Yup. Go and Google nandroid backup. You'll find much more info than I can stick in a comment.

Comment: And to note @EthanZ (who is right, btw) **Always** make nandroid backups, unless a better solution is in use. saves a lot of time.

Comment: @EthanZ - it seems that Mi Pad comes with an unlocked bootloader - so what does that mean - is it easy to get back to the original state?